# Rails: Check uniqueness of decrypted data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, encryption

I have a `users` table with an `encrypted_mobile_number` field. How can I check the uniqueness of the decrypted mobile_number without looping on all the mobile numbers?  I am using MessageEncrptor for the Encryption and Decryption of data. api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/MessageEncryptor.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Option 1**: Override the reader

```
validates encrypted_mobile_number, uniqueness: true

def encrypted_mobile_number
  # ... 
  crypt.decrypt_and_verify(@encrypted_mobile_number)    
end
```

**Option 2**: Create unique index

```
add_index :users, :encrypted_mobile_number, unique: true
```